super slow page load times in development environment in next js
I have just made initial setup not done anything else but its taking time like
- Local:        http://localhost:3000
  - Environments: .env.local

 ✓ Starting...
 ✓ Ready in 11.5s
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ✓ Compiled / in 33s (1216 modules)
 GET / 200 in 35795ms
 ○ Compiling /icon-23skhw.ico ...
 ✓ Compiled /icon-23skhw.ico in 14.1s (670 modules)
 GET /icon-23skhw.ico?7391c51acd569043 200 in 15000ms
 ○ Compiling /studio/[[...index]] ...
 ✓ Compiled /studio/[[...index]] in 49.7s (4653 modules)

{
  "name": "sanity-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 refine dev",
    "build": "refine build",
    "start": "refine start",
    "lint": "eslint '**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'",
    "refine": "refine"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@refinedev/cli": "^2.16.21",
    "@refinedev/core": "^4.47.1",
    "@refinedev/devtools": "^1.1.32",
    "@refinedev/kbar": "^1.3.6",
    "@refinedev/nextjs-router": "^6.0.0",
    "@refinedev/simple-rest": "^5.0.1",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.2",
    "@sanity/vision": "^3.39.0",
    "next": "^14.3.0-canary.29",
    "next-sanity": "^7.1.4",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "sanity": "^3.39.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.48.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "refine": {
    "projectId": "zyWWbe-LKvVYd-1rlurs"
  }
}

i have tried maltiple solutions from github forms and stack overflow youtube but not able to find proper solution

clear cookies site data & and cleared application data

npm install next@canary

next dev --turbo

updating not node version to lts
and some more things


